Continuity of optimizers of the Hopf--Lax formula
Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}$ be smooth and convex with at most linear growth (you can assume Lipschitzness if it simplifies). Fix any $t>0$. It is clear that a maximizer of the following Hopf--Lax type formula exists:
$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^d}\left\{f(x) - \frac{|x|^2}{t}\right\}.$$
Fix an arbitrary maximizer $x_0$ of this formula.
Question: Does there exist a sequence $(x_\epsilon)_{\epsilon>0}$ such that

for each $\epsilon>0$, $x_\epsilon$ is a maximizer of
$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^d}\left\{f(x) - \frac{|x|^2}{t+\epsilon}\right\},$$

and $x_\epsilon$ converges to $x_0$ as $\epsilon\to 0$?



This is false for $d=t=1$ and  $f$ such that $f(x)=x^2$ for $x\in[-1,1]$ and $f(x)=2|x|-1$ otherwise. The maximizers of $f(x)-x^2$ are all $x\in[-1,1]$ so $x_0=0$ for example, while the maximizers of $f(x)-\frac{x^2}{1+\epsilon}$ with $\epsilon>0$ are outside of $[-1,1]$, so there's no sequence that converges to $x_0$.
It's easy to modify this example to make $f$ smooth:
consider a smooth plateau function $\psi$ such that it's constantly $1$ for $|x|\leq 1$, it's constantly $0$ for $|x|\geq 2$ and it takes values in $[0,1)$ otherwise (it's important to exclude $1$ here) (for example you can symmetrize a smooth transition function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function?wprov=sfla1). Now $f$ is obtained integrating $\psi$ twice and imposing $f(0)=f'(0)=0$; in this way $f(x)-\frac{x^2}{1+\epsilon}$ has the same properties as before.
This example can also be adapted to any dimension $d$ by taking a radial function $f$.
